# GWT Window.open Add waiting message on new window (Used for document download)

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I am using a servlet to open a new tab with a link to download a document, what i need is to put a waiting message on the new tab because the download takes like 3 minutes to start, so i don't want the user to close the tab and try again
this is my servlet:

```
   @Override
    public void print() {

        final String Code = getView().getReportingPanel().aComboBox.getValue().getCode();

        String url = URL.encode(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "File?Code=" + Code + "&type=xlsx");
        com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(url, "FileDownload", "");    
    }
```

Thank you!,
Best Regards.

Comment: What is the question/problem, what doesn't work in this code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How should the message be displayed? Do you have control of the page (new tab) where the document is downloaded? However the variable `Code` should be written in small letters: `code`.

Comment: If the server is going to take some time before it is able to provide the download then you could use a timer to poll the servers status and update the page accordingly. When it is ready then send the download link.

Comment: The question/problem is that i need a new alert window in the new tab, and in that new tab i am opening with the window.open i do not have any content, at all, so i can't call the panel and show and alert, or anything. I need something to send to the window.open method that opens a waiting alert, or something untill the download starts.